# How to determine shape fill color in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, shapes, fill

I have a circle inside a MovieClip on stage with an instance name `holder`. I want to get color of that circle.

I am successfully targeting that circle as shown in code. I can change its color using transform, but I cannot find a way to actually check its color.

`holder.getChildAt(0);`

Comment: **BitmapData.draw(...)** copies your **DisplayObject** into a raster graphics, use **BitmapData.getPixel(...)** then to get the RGB value of a certain point.

Comment: To add to the above comment, shapes don't exactly have "a" color, say that circle can be filled with a gradient fill making the outcome differ by the position of that circle vs pixel taken.

Comment: As Organis said... I ended up with a complex function. In my project shape is always single color, but it can contain linear or radial alpha change, and it could be triangle or circle, so I cannot be sure which pixel to aim to get color... My solution is that I am drawing my shape as a Bitmap and iterating it's pixels until I get a pixel with transparency greater than zero. That pixel, contains, of course, color with alpha channel. I will post a reply to topic to show my result. :) Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, as I said in my reply, at the end, this is doing what I need. It could be a bit simplified and optimized, but, as far as my needs are going, it is fast enough! :)

```
function decimalToHex(decimal: int, padding: int = 2): String {
    var hex: String = Number(decimal).toString(16);
    while (hex.length < padding) {
        hex = "0" + hex;
    }
    return hex.toUpperCase();
}

function getColor(what: Object):void {
    var obj = what.getChildAt(0);
    var bmd: BitmapData = new BitmapData(obj.width, obj.height, true, 0x00ffffff);
    //In the 0x00ffffff color, leading two zeros are alpha channel
    bmd.draw(obj);
    var img = new Bitmap(bmd);
    var stp = "";
    for (var l: uint = 0; l < img.height && stp == ""; l++) {
        for (var m: uint = 0; m < img.width && stp == ""; m++) {
            var color = decimalToHex(bmd.getPixel32(m, l), 8);
            if (int(parseInt(color.substr(0, 2), 16)) > 0) {
                color = "#" + color.substr(2);
                stp = "stop";
                // Display color in a text box named as "what"'s name + letter "c"
                param.getChildByName(what.name + "c").text = color;
            }
        }
    }
}

getColor(holder); //As in question, my shape is inside it's holder
```

Comment: Credits goes to @Organis! :) His idea was an eye opener. :)